# Microsoft Excel Formula If Then

Tags: excel-formula

I have a question that relates to if, then formula on Microsoft excel.   Here is what I am trying to do but unable to write the correct formula:

```
IF(G2<=30000,"-g2*.003"))
```

If the column G2 is less than $30,000 then G2 x .003 will be subtracted. Otherwise, G2 x .002 will be subtracted.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(G2<30000, G2-G2*0.003, G2-G2*0.002)
```

Mind you say "less than 30k" but have "less or equal 30k" in your proposed code...

Comment: THE CALCULATED IF STATEMENT IS FIGURED FROM G2 BUT THE ANSWER GOES IN 02.  IF G2 IS LESS THAN $30,000 THEN G2 X .003 WILL BE SUBTRACTED; OTHERWISE G2 X .002 WILL BE SUBTRACTED.

Comment: I AM DISCOUNTING NEW AUTOS.. G2 IS THE MSRP (STICKER PRICE) COLUMN... IF G2 IS LESS THAN $30,000 THEN THE DISCOUNT WOULD BE G2 TIMES .003; OTHERWISE THE DISCOUNT IS G2 TIME .002.

Answer (score 0):

A little unclear what exact result you are going for but try this:

```
=IF(G2<30000, G2 - (G2*0.003), G2 - (G2 *0.002))
```

Comment: I AM DISCOUNTING NEW AUTOS..  G2 IS THE MSRP (STICKER PRICE) COLUMN...  IF G2 IS LESS THAN $30,000 THEN THE DISCOUNT WOULD BE G2 TIMES .003; OTHERWISE THE DISCOUNT IS G2 TIME .002.

Comment: Then the above formula would calculate the discounted price. To get the discount itself remove the G2- in both the true and false statements.